# How to query data which have timestamp between 2 timestamps from another table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to 2 tables.
Table A

| user | timestamp | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-06-06 00:00:00 | 1 |
| A | 2023-06-06 00:01:00 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |
| A | 2023-06-06 23:58:00 | 300 |
| A | 2023-06-06 23:59:00 | 200 |

Table B

| user | open_minute | close_minute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-06-06 07:00:00 | 2023-06-06 11:30:00 |
| A | 2023-06-06 12:30:00 | 2023-06-06 17:00:00 |

I tried to query all records with between 2 timestamp `open_minute` and `close_minute` from table B. But I have no idea.

Does anyone support me this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This looks like an elementary sql task. What research did you do before writing this post on SO? Have you crafted any code by yourself?

Comment: I'm doing my daily task. The scenario that I have the sensor data of the classroom and its timetable. I need to query sensor data in class hour to see the trend of classroom temperature. Btw, I have uploaded the code above.

Comment: I can't see your code, maybe you forgot to save the edits?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `inner join` :

```
select a.*
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.timestamp between b.open_minute and b.close_minute
```

If two ranges overlap then you will need to add `DISTINCT` to return only distinct values :

```
select distinct a.*
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.timestamp between b.open_minute and b.close_minute
```